# Ranking per user in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a load of weblogs from mobile users & I need to create a new column called 'hop'.

So, in the below, user 47294872934 went from India (at hour 0) to the UK (at hour 15). Hence, their first location was India and their second was UK.

So, I'd like a new column like this,

```
                      hour   hop
userid      country       
47294872934 India        0   1
            UK          15   2
82718927392 Portugal     4   3
            Spain        2   2
            UK           0   1
```

In the above, each user has a number of hops. User 82718927392 has travelled from UK (1) to Spain (2) to Portugal (3) over the course of the day.  This is a single day, so the higher the hour, the later the travel occurred.

I've tried rank (below) to do this, but it ranks across the entire dataset, rather than a single user. I also want the rank to be an int rather than a float.

Any help would be great!

```
In [12]: df2
Out[12]: 
                      hour
userid      country       
47294872934 India        0
            UK          15
82718927392 Portugal     4
            Spain        2
            UK           0

In [13]: df2.rank(ascending=True)
Out[13]: 
                      hour
userid      country       
47294872934 India      1.5
            UK         5.0
82718927392 Portugal   4.0
            Spain      3.0
            UK         1.5
```

**Including examples**

```
    In [32]: df2 = df.groupby(['userid', 'country'])[['hour']].min().groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1

In [33]: df2['hop'] = df2.sort_values('hour').groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-27bb4b4b86fa> in <module>()
----> 1 df2['hop'] = df2.sort_values('hour').groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in sort_values(self, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
   2444         """
   2445         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, 'inplace')
-> 2446         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   2447 
   2448         # GH 5856/5853

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_axis_number(self, axis)
    373                 pass
    374         raise ValueError('No axis named {0} for object type {1}'
--> 375                          .format(axis, type(self)))
    376 
    377     def _get_axis_name(self, axis):

ValueError: No axis named hour for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

**Further testing**

```
    ...: df['hop'] = df.groupby(level=0).hour.rank(method='dense').astype(int)

In [36]: df
Out[36]: 
         userid   country      date  hour  hop
0   82718927392        UK  20101025     0    1
1   82718927392        UK  20101025     1    1
2   82718927392        UK  20101025     1    1
3   82718927392        UK  20101025     1    1
4   82718927392     Spain  20101025     2    1
5   82718927392     Spain  20101025     2    1
6   82718927392     Spain  20101025     2    1
7   82718927392     Spain  20101025     3    1
8   82718927392  Portugal  20101025     4    1
9   82718927392  Portugal  20101025     5    1
10  47294872934     India  20101025     0    1
11  47294872934     India  20101025     0    1
12  47294872934     India  20101025     1    1
13  47294872934        UK  20101025    15    1
14  47294872934        UK  20101025    17    1
15  47294872934        UK  20101025    19    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want a counter within each `userid`, you need to first groupby that column.

#### `sort_values` + `groupby` + `cumcount`

```
df['hop'] = df.sort_values('hour').groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1

                      hour  hop
userid      country            
47294872934 India        0    1
            UK          15    2
82718927392 Portugal     4    3
            Spain        2    2
            UK           0    1
```

#### `groupby` + `rank`

```
df['hop'] = df.groupby(level=0).hour.rank(method='dense').astype(int)

                      hour  hop
userid      country            
47294872934 India        0    1
            UK          15    2
82718927392 Portugal     4    3
            Spain        2    2
            UK           0    1
```

If a user has multiple countries at the same hour, `cumcount` will increment the count, while `rank` will not.

Comment: Thank you for your response! - I've tried the above & get an error that there is no column named hour (I guess as I'm aggregating on it) - do you know how I stop this? Error shown in post above ^^

Comment: @kikee1222 I think when you run that first line of code (`In[32]`) to define `df2` you no longer have a column named hour. Why do you even need that line? My solution will work for your multiIndex (level_0 is `user_id`, level_1 is `country`) with a column named hour. So use either of those after whatever line of code prints out the `DataFrames` you provided.

Comment: Hi - I've just updated the solution to that - it sets everything to hop1 and doesn't take only the first transaction in each country, which is what I am trying to do